# competing definitions for polytope dual

Tags: polytopes

Along with a polytope P one has the notion of its dual which is officially defined via the inner product.  However, in three dimensions at least, the dual is often pictured simply by placing a point in each face of P and then taking the convex hull.  Will this same method work in general?

Question: Let P be an n-dimensional polytope.  Place points at the barycenter of each facet of P and designate by $\,$Q$\,$ the convex hull of these points.  $\,$Is the resulting polytope$\,$ Q$\,$ combinatorially equivalent to the dual of$\,$ P$\,$?

Thanks.

Comment: This works almost never, not even in 3D (or 2D). This technique works only for the most symmetric cases, and requires *at least* that the polytope has an insphere, but this is far from sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

No.  For example, let P be a regular icosahedron with each vertex perturbed randomly by a small amount.  Your constructed Q will consist of 36 triangles, rather than 12 pentagons.